# Maven deploy: forcing the deploy even if artifact already exists

Tags: maven

I'm building a project, which is made up from several (sometimes unrelated) modules and some more non standard java modules (built with ANT).

Each maven module is deployed to the releases repository on completion.

If the build fails in the middle, I might have some modules already deployed, so if I try to rebuild, the new attempt to deploy will fail since the artifacts are already deployed.

Is it possible to force a deploy or instead, remove the deployed artifact before I deploy again?

Comment: try mvn release:rollback

Comment: Why would the deploy fail? If you deploy artifact with the same version, it will just overwrite the existing one.

Comment: Andrew - AFAIK, if you try to re-deploy an existing artifact, you will fail.

Comment: @om39a A mvn release:rollback will not remove artifacts from repository.

Comment: The usual setup of repository managers is not to allow a redeployment of artifacts for good reasons. The question is: Why would a deploy fail? If it fails something is wrong and your configuration does not work.

Comment: @khmarbaise - it's not that the deployment fails. It's a complete build process that fails. Some of the modules are already deployed... and some not. I want to rollback/cancel the deployed ones, so I can re-build (which will re-deploy the failed modules).

Comment: And what's the reason for failing? Error messages ?

Comment: Yes. Errors in other part of the build. The "Build" is made up of many modules (some maven, some not). A "Passed" build will one where all modules were built successfully.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It sounds like the middleware admins have configured your remote repo instance (Nexus or Artifactory or whatever) to not allow artifact redeployment, and as @khmarbaise says there are good reasons for that.  Nexus can be configured to allow artifact deletion by users in a particular role or with artifact deletion privileges.  If your admins have it set up that way perhaps you can request the delete privilege and remove the offending artifacts.  Or, perhaps the Nexus admin will agree to do it for you.

If neither of these is possible, here are some things to try which might keep this from happening in the future:

1. If you are using the `release` plugin, do a dry run (`-DdryRun=true` on the release:prepare command line) first.  Maven should report any errors without committing to SCM.
2. Try running `mvn install` on your group of projects first.  This will install the artifacts to your local repo, not the remote.  If there's a problem you can whack the artifacts out of your local repo and start from scratch, repeating until you get a complete build.
3. If you are running a multi-module build, there are [command line options](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/_using_advanced_reactor_options.html) that allow resuming a Maven build from a particular project forward.
4. Define `-Dmaven.deploy.skip=true` on the Maven command line.  This is similar to suggestion #2, except Maven will actually load & configure the [deploy plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html), it just won't do the actual deploy to the remote repo.  Once everything works, remove the skip property.

Comment: All good suggestions. I think I will go for option 4 or similar... Thx!

Comment: I have a similar problem, everything went fine till i got a 502 (Proxy Error) I assume that my uni server thought my connection is a threat. Now I get 400 (Bad Request) because the artifacts are already on the nexus server. Is there a way to resume a release:perform?

I can delete the artifacts but this is a lot of work in the nexus control panel. It seems I have to delete every version sub-folder of the multi-module project by hand. I will try to upload from within the uni network next time, though!

Answer (score 14):

I know it might be late, but in Nexus there's an option where allows the redeployment of artifacts.

[image]

Just select the repositories in the left, choose the repository you want to change the policy and then set it to Allow Redeploy.

Comment: This is a good option, but I'm interested in such a capability from my build only, and not allow anyone to re-deploy a released artifact. Can I enable it at build time and disable when build is done?

Comment: don't think it is possible because who decides if the artifact can be redeployed is the server, not the client

Answer (score 5):

The possible options have been increased ;)

Use the parameter deployAtEnd (More information: [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#deployAtEnd)). With this parameter the artifacts are deployed only, if all artifacts were built successfully.