# mvn deploy: Resource to deploy not found

Tags: maven, artifactory

I just use maven with most simple configuration:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.app.myApp.my-dependencies</groupId>
<artifactId>this-dependency</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>

<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>mySnapshotsLocal</id>
        <name>my-snapshot-local</name>
        <url>http://maven.myRepo/artifactory/my-snapshot-local</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
        <id>myLocal</id>
        <name>my-release-local</name>
        <url>http://maven.myRepo/artifactory/my-release-local</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

I try to use

```
mvn deploy
```

command to upload dependencies to Artifactory, which works great, but when I make a change in the file and run the command again, it gives me:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Error deploying artifact
: Resource to deploy not found: File: http://maven.myRepo/artifactory/my-release-local
/com/app/myApp/my-dependencies/this-dependency
0.0.1/dependency-0.0.1.jar does not exist
```

Does it mean mvn deploy cannot handle replacing existing dependency? It seems to me that the command only works well for just once...

## UPDATE

here is the full stacktrace

```
[INFO] [deploy:deploy {execution: default-deploy}]
Uploading: http://maven.myRepo/artifactory/my-release-local/com/app/myApp/my-dependencies/this-dependency0.0.1-/dependency-0.0.1.jar
4/30K
8/30K
12/30K
16/30K
20/30K
24/30K
28/30K
30/30K
[INFO]------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error deploying artifact: Resource to deploy not found: File: http://maven.myRepo/artifactory/my-release-local/com/app/myApp/my-dependencies/this-dependency0.0.1-/dependency-0.0.1.jar does not exist

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Error deploying artifact: Resource to deploy not found: File: 
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Error deploying artifact: Resource to deploy not found: File: http://maven.myRepo/artifactory/my-release-local/com/app/myApp/my-dependencies/this-dependency0.0.1-/dependency-0.0.1.jar does not exist
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error deploying artifact: Resource to deploy not found: File: http://maven.myRepo/artifactory/my-release-local/com/app/myApp/my-dependencies/this-dependency0.0.1-/dependency-0.0.1.jar does not exist
at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:195)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Error deploying artifact: Resource to deploy not found: File: http://maven.myRepo/artifactory/my-release-local/com/app/myApp/my-dependencies/this-dependency0.0.1-/dependency-0.0.1.jar does not exist
at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:121)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:173)
... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Resource to deploy not found: File: http://maven.myRepo/artifactory/my-release-local/com/app/myApp/my-dependencies/this-dependency0.0.1-/dependency-0.0.1.jar does not exist
at org.apache.maven.artifact.manager.DefaultWagonManager.putRemoteFile(DefaultWagonManager.java:356)
at org.apache.maven.artifact.manager.DefaultWagonManager.putArtifact(DefaultWagonManager.java:227)
at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:107)
... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.ResourceDoesNotExistException: File: http://maven.myRepo/artifactory/my-release-local/com/app/myApp/my-dependencies/this-dependency0.0.1-/dependency-0.0.1.jar does not exist
at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.finishPutTransfer(LightweightHttpWagon.java:200)
at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.putTransfer(AbstractWagon.java:413)
at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.transfer(AbstractWagon.java:392)
at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.putTransfer(AbstractWagon.java:365)
at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.put(StreamWagon.java:163)
at org.apache.maven.artifact.manager.DefaultWagonManager.putRemoteFile(DefaultWagonManager.java:317)
... 22 more
```

Comment: Which version of Maven? Trying to deploy a release a second time should be avoided by the repository manager but the erorr message looks wrong...BTW: Can you show the full error output and not only an excerpt.. What did you change?

Comment: The usual cause of this error is a wrong repository URL. Make sure that the URL you have in the pom file did not change and is the correct one

Comment: @khmarbaise It happens on Maven 2. thanks

Comment: @khmarbaise also update the stacktrace

Comment: @drorb The url looks correct, but if it is incorrect why it works for the first time?

Comment: Apart from being on [Maven 2...](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html). Is this build a multi module build? Furthermore if you make changes? What does this mean? Changes in POM or in code and just retrying to deploy a second time which is not allowed on a maven repository (releases are immutable).

Comment: @khmarbaise i only made change in the code. I update the post and put more stack trace :)  When run `deploy` command, I can see maven uploading the file to repository(see the stack trace), but it looks like if the file has been deployed once maven never allow or recognize the uploaded file (may be in the cache I guess?).

Comment: @khmarbaise I guess it may be an issue in artifactory configuration? It looks mvn deploy did the job but artifactory some how didn't generate correct pom in the repo?

Comment: @khmarbaise  I did a little research and it looks you have share some great opinion in a similar case :) ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175288/maven-deploy-forcing-the-deploy-even-if-artifact-already-exists

Comment: @Dreamer the URL Maven is logging is broken, specifically this part: `this-dependency0.0.1-` which should be `this-dependency/0.0.1`. Do you see any errors in the artifactory.log? do you see the request in the Artifactory request.log?